# How do I save an EF object hierarchy to db when I built the EF object from DTOs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an editor that uses Entity Framework for db-access. The editor is a clientside editor that works via JavaScript. When the user clicks the save-button JavaScript calls my ASP.NET MVC method with the data as a JSON-string. The data is an object containing a list of nodes. I use inheritance in EF to allow the nodes to be of different types. The JSON that is sent from the browser is converted by MVC automatically to a DTO object. I then create EF-objects based on the DTO object. My question is how do I save the modifications to all the objects?

Right now I do the following:

```
// Convert my DTO object to a EF db object
Document dbDoc = dtoDoc.ToEFDocument();

using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    db.ApplyCurrentValues("Documents", doc);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works but it only updates the properties in the document object (not the changes that was made in the nodes collection).

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: How can I use db.include() when I'm not actually asking the db for the data, but I'm building the objects myself?

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your DTOs must also track information about changes an user did. You must track:

- Which entities were updated
- Which entities were removed
- Which entities were added
- Which independent associations (many-to-many or one-to-many without mapped FK) were added
- Which independent associations were removed

Once you get this information on the server you must use it to correctly set state of every entity you want to save to database. There is no automatic mechanism for doing this in EF and `ApplyCurrentValues` only works for single entity (not for whole entity graph).

Doing this without information about changes usually requires loading all modified data from database and update them from DTOs instead of creating disconnected entities from DTO.

Comment: Ok.. This poses a much bigger challenge than I expected then. I'm using KnockoutJS for client side code. That means I have to track everything the client does and handle the changes back in C# myself. I may try to just delete everything in the db to do with the document and then save the new version that was sent from the client.